# how to use non-IE debugger in visual studio 2005?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, internet-explorer, firefox, visual-studio-2005

I am building an asp.net website on vs2005 (c#) and I can't find a way to debug using a browser that is not IE.

I managed to open pages in non-debug mode with different browsers by using "browse with..." on any file's context menu and even setting the desired browser as default if i wish.
but I can't find a way to make this alternative browser work when I do it in debug mode (start debugging button/F5).

Is there any way to do this? I searched around a lot and all I found is a solution for vs2003 which doesn't seem to work in vs2005.

thanks,
Asaf